# Applying CSS classes only to the parent (current) p:panelGrid

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

The following `<p:panelGrid>` contains another `<p:panelGrid>`s.

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="panelgrid-noborder">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:outputText value="1"/>
        <h:outputText value="2"/>
    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:outputText value="1"/>
        <h:outputText value="2"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Just as an example, I need to remove all borders only from the parent/outer(most) `<p:panelGrid>`.

The following CSS class,

```css
.panelgrid-noborder.ui-panelgrid tr, .panelgrid-noborder.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border: none;
}
```

Removes borders from all `<p:panelGrid>`s.

I also tried using a plain CSS class like,

```css
.panelgrid-noborder {
    border: none;
}
```

and give it to the `columnClasses` attribute - `columnClasses="panelgrid-noborder"` but it does not remove borders at all.

How to remove borders from a parent `<p:panelGrid>` i.e CSS classes should only be applied to the current `<p:panelGrid>` to which theses classes are specified? This should not affect any other `<p:panelGrid>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `.panelgrid-noborder.ui-panelgrid tr` basically means *"match **every** `<tr>` of an element having class `panelgrid-noborder ui-panelgrid`"*.

You only want to match the immediate child. You need to use a more specific [selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) for that, specifically the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) selector `E > F`.

So, this should do:

```css
.panelgrid-noborder.ui-panelgrid > tbody > tr, 
.panelgrid-noborder.ui-panelgrid > tbody > tr > td {
    border: none;
}
```

Please note that browsers implicitly put `<tr>` elements in `<tbody>` when no `<thead>` or `<tfoot>` is specified. You can see it in browser's HTML DOM tree inspector.

#### See also:

- [CSS tutorial](http://htmldog.com/guides/css/)